# Toolbar crashing on Kitkat

Tags: android

I have a custom toolbar on my app and it seems to be crashing when run on a kitkat device.

The error I get is:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

It's crashing when it loads the mainActivity.

My toolbar xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_background"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

I looked around and the only solutions of fixing this problem was because of `?attr` tags which I don't have.

The full error log shows:

```
05-11 18:26:26.426 8832-8832/com.company.company E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.company.company, PID: 8832
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.company.company/com.company.company.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:621)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:840)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:840)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
       at com.company.company.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:595)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:840) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:840) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
       at com.company.company.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38) 
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f020083 a=-1 r=0x7f020083}
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2073)
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
       at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3554)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:470)
       at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:235)
       at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:231)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:595) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:840) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:840) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
       at com.company.company.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38) 
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

which crashes at:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:**

I fixed the toolbar problem, in my coordinatorLayout I was just including my toolbar. Now it is in their I no longer get that error.

But I get a new error,

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Comment: @AlexKamenkov it is extending AppCompatActivity

Comment: @AlexKamenkov have you added compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+' dependency in gradle and supportLibrary=true in defaultConfig

Answer (score 0):

[AppBarLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html) is heavily depends on being used as a direct child within a CoordinatorLayout. If you use AppBarLayout within a different ViewGroup, most of it's functionality will not work.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

     <!-- Your scrolling content -->

 </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="match_parent">

     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
             ...
             app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

     <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
             ...
             app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

 </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Technically it already is in a coordinatorLayout, I have an xml file that includes the toolbar and then has a fragment container in it

Comment: I eddited my question